# Use Javascript Timer in Node.Js Script to fire an event at certain time

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, timer

I have 40 or more timer in my Node script (a timer for per connection) to count time and call a function when it's finished.
For another job, i want call a function at 23:59; so i have two solution:

1. Use another Java script timer to check time and call my function at 23:59.
2. Use Linux schedule to emit an event at 23:59.

Which is more logical? Is there another solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at node-cron module, I've used this to schedule recurring tasks on Node apps before:

[Node Cron](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron)